# Zero Traffic on while running pipeline application in dpdk

Tags: virtualbox, pipe, traffic

I have two Virtual Machines. Both of them have their port bridged. On one VM I run Pktgen DPDK to generate traffic. On the other VM my goal is to run DPDK's pipeline application. Now When I run pipeline application, with l2fwd.cli as configuration file. After that I use telnet 127.0.0.1 8086 to enter in the pipeline. Now When I read port 0 I receive 0 packets, despite the fact that traffic is running. Any solution? Also When I run simple DPDK's L2fwd application, I receive the packets in real time, but fail to receive When I am in pipeline Application.[Pipeline Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h2OQ.png) [Pipeline 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX01H.png) [Telnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOwhn.png)  [Pktgen Dpdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAJ0T.png)

Comment: on VM1 when running with linux driver, are the packets received? One can check with `tcpdump`. Please update

Comment: Yes Packets are Going from VM1 to VM2 but not receiving back to from VM2 to VM1

Comment: tcpdump put the NIC interface in promiscuous mode, Using DPDK pipeline application, did you enable the DPDK ports `link` in promiscuous mode? I am not able to identify from the screenshot.

Comment: are there any updates @saifullah ?

Comment: @saidullah are there any updates from your end? Did you try turning on the promiscuous mode as suggested?

Comment: Hi There @VipinVarghese. Extremely sorry for the late reply. The above method also didn't worked either. After that we had to shift to another tasks by the company and we didn't get time to test it further.

Comment: thanks for the update, as requested via skype please share the logs to better understand the problem as the same works for me.